# want to use startwith( ) method as !startwith( )?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read strings from a text file that looks like this:

```
 # hello my name is captain
1111 $3340 4
1211 $9182 5
1211 $9192 9
```

```java
if(!line.startsWith("#")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This prints out everything except the `#`:

```
 hello my name is captain
1111 $3340 4
1211 $9182 5
1211 $9192 9
```

I cant find any examples that use the `!` symbol and cant tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you post the code how you read data from the file ??

Comment: Please could you clarify your goal? Do you just want to print out all the lines in the file that do not begin with #?

Comment: It's possible your text file has a Unicode BOM character, which Java isn't reading appropriately, so it doesn't consider the `#` character as the first in the line.

Comment: Make sure your first line is not composed of 2 separate lines, one with the # only and the rest on the second line.

Comment: @Dai couldn't be - the `#` is not printed but the rest does.

Comment: i thkn the line is not starting with a `#`, it could be starting with a white space .

Comment: ahh i think i got it... i just added this code.                  StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

Comment: It starts with a space, not '#'. There's your problem,

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The error in your code contains a space before the comments. So check trimming it.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("path-to-file")));

String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    if (!line.trim().startsWith("#")){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```